# How to set focus on controls using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Am using textboxes in various places of my project.I used autofocus on textbox control and it worked fine but in partially loading pages autofocus is not working properly.

So can anyone please tel me is there any way to create a separate directive in angularjs , so that i can apply that directive  on which control i need to set focus in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an autofocus directive:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('autofocus', function($timeout) {
   return function(scope, element, attr) {
      $timeout(function() {
          element[0].focus();
      }, 0, false);
   }
})
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5E9aL/)